# passing custom java objects to webEngine executeScript

Tags: javafx-2

I have person class

```
Person p = new Person();
.......
.....
```

following is not working

```
webEngine.executeScript("add(" + p +  ")");
```

and in html

```
function add(obj)
{
   document.getElementById("helloprompt").innerHTML= obj.name; // error
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok got it first i had to get JSObject and then call the function

```
JSObject jsobj = (JSObject)webEngine.executeScript("window");
jsobj.call("add", p);
```